# select2 set multiple selected values

Tags: javascript, select, jquery-select2

I have the following select2:

```
<select id="e1" multiple style="width: 250px;" name="attributes[]">
    <?php if(isset($vars['attributes'])):?>
        <?php foreach($vars['attributes'] as $attribute):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $attribute['id'];?>"><?php echo $attribute['name'];?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif;?>
</select>
```

Now i load some of the data via. Ajax:

which lists the following array:

[image]

Now i wish to add these 3 as selected values to my select2.

How do i do that?

**update**

HEre is my code so far:

```
    var _lst = document.getElementById('e1');
var optCount = _lst.options.length;
for (var i=0 ; i<data['attributes'].length; i++){
    var opt = new Option(data['attributes'][i]['name'],data['attributes'][i]['id']);
    _lst.options[optCount+i] = opt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way : [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/evoilliot/1a1rbnww/)

I'm not sure about your `attributes` type and structure (json ? array ?)
You can amend the code for your purpose.

Comment: The picture is taking from the debugger in PHPStorm. however it will be encoded into json

Comment: Wait i can see it adds it to the option list but does not set it as selected

Comment: it still doesnt add them as selected in your JS fiddle or is mine cached?

Comment: if you're ok with this answer, could you please mark it as valid with the green tick ? Many thanks ;)